# create Widget & Error in android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-widget

When I'm creating a widget in android studio, I met with this error, the problem is?

Rendering Problems 
The following classes could not be found:
- include (Fix Build Path)
 Tip: Try to build the project.

Answer (score 0):

Use a more stable Android Version. Change the API to a stable one API 22( Android 5.1 Lollipop) when running your project.